# Spring conflict with Maven's jar packaging

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jar

I'm experiencing some weird behavior from Spring, Maven and Tomcat interaction. Everytime I use jar packaging in POM, an exception is thrown:

```
Severe: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:25)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:164)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:340)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Otherwise, when I clean Tomcat, another exception raises (then again using jar as packaging):

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp(5,62) Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:/C:/tomcat/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.2.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:40)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:407)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:218)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:183)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:450)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1397)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:130)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:255)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:185)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:321)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:592)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:328)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
```

When I change POM to war packaging, everything runs well. Why in the World Maven's (only) jar packaging conflits with jstl-1.2.jar? What is a workaround? Thanks!

Edit: Entyre POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
  <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>description text</description>
  <packaging>war</packaging> <!-- <== ISSUE HERE! -->

    <properties>

        <!-- Generic properties -->
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <!-- Web -->
        <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <servlet.version>2.5</servlet.version>


        <!-- Spring -->
        <spring-framework.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>

        <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
        <hibernate.version>4.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>

        <!-- Test -->
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
            <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
            <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Other Web dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.32</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.11</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging with SLF4J & LogBack -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
           <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
           <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
</project>
```

Comment: Please share the relevant sections of the pom if possible.

Comment: Are there any explicit dependencies on servlet-api and/or jsp api in your pom? By 'explicit' I mean not `provided` ones.

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, could you check your pom's dependency hierarchy. Maybe some conflicting dependencies show up.

Comment: Did you try to remove jstl? Spring webmvc 4.0.6 [depens on jstl-1.2.1](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.6.RELEASE) anyway.

Comment: Wait... Why would a web app ever be a jar?

Comment: @kaqqao, in this momment I'm just rebuilding application, and in this application there's classes which I'm using in another project. In a latter momment I'm going to disable Web feature and these classes are going to be contained in a service.